# c error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant

Tags: c, switch-statement, sdl

This is the switch case concerned by the error:

```
switch(event.type)
        {
        case SDL_Quit:
            for (int i=0;i<NUMMENU;i++)
                SDL_FreeSurface(menus[i]);
            return 1;

        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            x=event.motion.x;
            y=event.motion.y;
            for(int i=0;i<NUMMENU;i++)
            {
                if(x>=position[i].x && x<=position[i].x+position[i].w && y>=position[i].y && y<=position[i].y+position[i].h)
                    {
                    if(!selected[i])
                    {
                        selected[i]=1;
                        SDL_FreeSurface(menus[i]);
                        menus[i]=TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,labels[i],color[1]);
                    }
                }else{
                        if(selected[i])
                        {
                            selected[i]=0;
                            SDL_FreeSurface(menus[i]);
                            menus[i]=TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,labels[i],color[0]);
                        }
                      }
            }

        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x=event.button.x;
            y=event.button.y;
            for(int i=0;i<NUMMENU;i++)
                if(x>=position[1].x && x<=position[1].x+position[i].w && y>=position[i].y && y<=position[i].y+position[i].h)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<NUMMENU;j++)
                        SDL_FreeSurface(menus[j]);
                    return i;
                }
                break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            if(event.key.keysym.sym==SDLK_ESCAPE)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<NUMMENU;i++)
                    SDL_FreeSurface(menus[i]);
                return 0;
            }

        }
```

I have this error and I haven't any idea of why and what should I do to resolve this. I have tried to add break; at the end of each case but no results.

If you need more code or further information, I can give precisions.

Regards,

Comment: have you tried moving the declaration of variable `i` outside the case statements

Comment: `SDL_xxx` are probably const variables not macros, and those are not allowed to be used as case labels.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [switch case: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069737/switch-case-error-case-label-does-not-reduce-to-an-integer-constant)

Comment: @Marlon: Huh? I would assume `SDL_Quit` is not an integer constant but maybe a function. But if it is an integer constant then of course it's valid as a case label.

Comment: Perhaps that was supposed to be `SDL_QUIT`.

Comment: Indeed, it was only a fail on the SDL_Quit, SDL_QUIT resolved the problem.. Could you make an answer, to uprate it and agree as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the function `void SDL_Quit(void)` rather than the `SDL_QUIT` event type at line 3.

```
case SDL_Quit:
     ^^^^^^^^
        for (int i=0;i<NUMMENU;i++)
            SDL_FreeSurface(menus[i]);
        return 1;
```

Comment: This is what I suspected (see my comments) but I'm not familiar with SDL. Thanks for getting the right info for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `case` labels such as `SDL_Quit/SDL_MOUSEMOTION...` could not be integer constants. For example its valid if they are characters labels but not something like `const char *`  string literals which are not integer constants.